# sed regular expression failure

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I have a sample file with the contents:

```
Filesystem                                         512-blocks       Used  Available Capacity   iused      ifree %iused  Mounted on
/dev/disk0s2                                        467182912  419318824   47352088    90%  52478851    5919011   90%   /
devfs                                                     419        419          0   100%       727          0  100%   /dev
/dev/disk1s2                                        975093952  673515008  301578944    70%  84189374   37697368   69%   /Volumes/Local_Storage
map -hosts                                                  0          0          0   100%         0          0  100%   /net
map auto_home                                               0          0          0   100%         0          0  100%   /home
localhost:/l3ZTI82fIEDeEEIvUkf44A                   467182912  467182912          0   100%         0          0  100%   /Volumes/MobileBackups
/dev/disk2s2                                       1952853344 1925763856   27089488    99% 240720480    3386186   99%   /Volumes/SK Backup
/dev/disk3s2                                        199328216   88909928  110418288    45%  11113739   13802286   45%   /Volumes/Secure_Storage
/dev/disk4s2                                         59328216   51456432    7871784    87%   6432052     983973   87%   /Volumes/Secure
/dev/disk5s2                                         60000000   12713448   47286552    22%   1589179    5910819   21%   /Volumes/Secure_Personal
//chris@SK-HQ-SRV05.internal.com/Storage 4294701048 1128302984 3166398064    27% 141037871  395799758   26%   /Volumes/Storage
/dev/disk6s2                                           200000       9952     190048     5%      1242      23756    5%   /Volumes/VAULT
//chris@172.20.1.76/chris.s           467182912  437521864   29661048    94%  54690231    3707631   94%   /Volumes/chris.schmitz
//chris@hq-srv03/NET              167563256   50264576  117298680    30%         0 18446744073709551615    0%   /Volumes/NETLOGON
```

And I'm working on pulling out just the ip addresses and host names from the file. Right now I'm working on grabbing the ips using the following pattern:

```
cat dfsample.txt | awk '/@/' | sed -E 's/.*([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}).*/\1/g'
```

With unexpected results:

```
//chris@SK-HQ-SRV05.internal.com/Storage 4294701048 1128302984 3166398064    27% 141037871  395799758   26%   /Volumes/Storage
2.20.1.76
//chris@hq-srv03/NET               167563256   50264576  117298680    30%         0 18446744073709551615    0%   /Volumes/NETLOGON
```

My expectation for the sed section was that the `.*` before and after the pattern defined in the parens would select the entire line and when I substituted the line for the pattern found within the parens using the `\1` it would substitute the entire line with the found pattern leaving only the ip address.

For some reason the first two digits of my ip address is getting cut off. When I try the pattern in the parens in sublime it finds the ip without an issue. What is it that I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed -nr 's,^//[^@/]*@([^/]*)/.*,\1,p'
```

gets both hostnames and IP addresses and won't be fooled by "interesting" volume names.

If your sed doesn't have the `r` flag, the escaping isn't too ugly on this one, I probably should have given it just this way:

```
sed -n 's,^//[^@/]*@\([^/]*\)/.*,\1,p'
```

(edit: `[^@]` -> `[^@/]` safety play)

Comment: +1 for providing a complete solution; using `-E` instead of `-r` should work for the OP (incidentally, `-E` works with GNU `sed` too (as an alias for `-r`), but it's not documented).

Comment: So if I understand this correctly, the regular expression in the first sed section is basically saying "find all lines beginning with a double forward slash, 0 or more characters that are not "@" until you get to "@", then zero or more characters that are not a forward slash (remember this pattern) until you get to a forward slash, then zero or more of any characters not including a new line, and substitute that with the stored pattern and print it", Right? It makes sense, I just want to make sure I fully understand the why behind the pattern.

Comment: One quick additional question. When I put this into my actual bash script, set the result to a variable, and then check it by echoing the variable it returns the result all on one line. If I fire `df | sed -nE 's|//[^@]*@([^/]*)/.*|\1|p'` directly from the command line it returns the results on separate lines. I've tried inserting a new line after each `\1` to force a new line but it doesn't seem to do it either. Is there a reason the variable gets everything inline?

Comment: You set the variable to the entire result so the newlines are just field separators.  How newlines are treated is context-dependent and idiosyncratic with just about every tool, you have to get a feel for when they'll be treated as something more significant than ordinary whitespace.  Think of it like english spelling, it's the way it is because it made sense to somebody, somewhere, and it's too late to fix it now.

Comment: Ah, understood. I read up on how the internal field separator works and also on how I would pass the results of my command into an array. It turns out I didn't need to alter the IFS value since host names and ip addresses inherently wouldn't have spaces in between them, but it was still good to read about the IFS. I altered my variable declaration to `externalMounts=($( df | sed -nE 's|//[^@]*@([^/]*)/.*[^$]|\1|p' ))` and now it stacks the results neatly into an array that I can then walk over with the rest of my script. Thanks again!

Comment: Sorry, I meant `externalMounts=($( df | sed -nE 's|//[^@]*@([^/]*)/.*|\1|p' ))`

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you `sed` would, by default, print lines whether the pattern matched or not.  Use `-n` to disable automatic printing of pattern space and `p` to print the current pattern space:

```
sed -En '/@/{s/.*([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}).*/\1/p;}' inputfile
```

This would produce `2.20.1.76` for your input.  Also note that you don't need the `awk` pipeline in order to filter the data.

Comment: +1; to make it work on OSX, a `;` must go before the closing `}` (alternatively, don't enclose the `s` command in `{...}` at all).

Comment: @mklement0 BSD sed should be happy now `:)`

Comment: :) The OP doesn't say so explicitly, but the use of `-E` suggests OSX / BSD.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to do it with `awk`

```
awk '/@/ {split($1,a,"[@/]");print a[4]}' file
SK-HQ-SRV05.internal.com
172.20.1.76
hq-srv03
```

This finds all line with `@`, then split the line by `@` or `/`
It then prints part `4` from the split.